# Python: JDBC Connection Error using JayDeBeApi

Tags: java, python, jdbc, jpype, jaydebeapi

I'm facing an error while running following code. Please help me solving this issue or suggest an alternative way to connect Vertica server via JDBC.

I have also tried connecting using pyspark. But with pyspark we are not able to execute sql query in vertica server.

*System Configuration:*

Linux with python 3.7.0

jaydebeapi version - 1.1.1

jpype version - 0.7.2

```
import jaydebeapi
import jpype

jdbc_url = 'jdbc:vertica://XX.XX.XXX.XXX/DATA?XXXXX'
vertica_properties={"user": "XXXX", "password": "XXXXX"}

jars = ['XXXX/vertica-jdbc-9.3.1-0.jar', 
        'XXXX/vertica-spark2.1_scala2.11.jar', 
        'XXXX/CustomVerticaDialect.jar']

connection = jaydebeapi.connect(jclassname='com.vertica.jdbc.Driver', url=jdbc_url, driver_args=vertica_properties, jars=jars)
connection
```

**ERROR**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-cc7d2752ecd8> in <module>()
----> 1 connection = jaydebeapi.connect(jclassname='com.vertica.jdbc.Driver', url=jdbc_url, driver_args=vertica_properties, jars=jars)
      2 connection

/BDAPP/python/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jaydebeapi/__init__.py in connect(jclassname, url, driver_args, jars, libs)
    379     else:
    380         libs = []
--> 381     jconn = _jdbc_connect(jclassname, url, driver_args, jars, libs)
    382     return Connection(jconn, _converters)
    383 

/BDAPP/python/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jaydebeapi/__init__.py in _jdbc_connect_jpype(jclassname, url, driver_args, jars, libs)
    180         types = jpype.java.sql.Types
    181         types_map = {}
--> 182         for i in types.__javaclass__.getClassFields():
    183             types_map[i.getName()] = i.getStaticAttribute()
    184         _init_types(types_map)

AttributeError: type object 'java.sql.Types' has no attribute '__javaclass__'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jaydebeapi seems to be incompatible with jpype 0.7.2 as of Mar 2020. Here is the github page that points out this issue: http://github.com/baztian/jaydebeapi/issues/99.

The solution as per the github page is to downgrade jpype to jpype 0.6.3 using either:

```
pip install JPype1==0.6.3 --force-reinstall
```

or

```
conda install -c conda-forge JPype1=0.6.3 --force-reinstall
```

Downgrading jpype worked for me

Comment: This problem has been fixed, just upgrade to JayDeBeApi to 1.2.3 that using JPype1 v0.7.5

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade to JayDeBeApi>=1.2.1. Starting from JPype1 0.7.0 some non backwards compatible changes have been introduced. Newer JayDeBeApi versions can deal with that.

```
pip install --upgrade JayDeBeApi
```